# angular 7 - Radio change not showing hidden text

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm very new to angular. I'm trying to make a div show when I select a value in my radio group. Can you please help.

I'm not sure how or if I need a change event.

Thanks

```html
    <label>
      Gender:<br><br>
      Male<br>
      <input type="radio" value="male" formControlName="gender" >
      Female<br>
      <input type="radio" value="female" formControlName="gender" >
      <div *ngIf="submitted && messageForm.controls.gender.errors" class="error">
          <div *ngIf="messageForm.controls.gender.errors.required">A gender is required</div>
        </div>
    </label>

    <div *ngIf="messageForm.controls.gender ==='male'">
      show this
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
<div *ngIf="messageForm.get('gender').value ==='male'">
```

Comment: @Hello-World Please mark this as the answer to close the question if it has solved your problem rather than just saying "Thank so much"

Answer (score 2):

If your do not want to create and destroy you div every time the user toggles the radio button you can use css display attribute to hide and show the div.

```
<div [style.display]="!messageForm.get('gender').value ==='male' ? 'block' : 'none'">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use template variable and check the input checked value

```
<label>
  Gender:<br><br>
  Male<br>
  <input type="radio" value="male" formControlName="gender" #maleElem >
  Female<br>
  <input type="radio" value="female" formControlName="gender" >
</label>

<div *ngIf="maleElem.checked">
  show this
</div>
```

or you can get the value of gender form control like this

```
<div *ngIf="messageForm.get('gender').value === 'male'">
  show this
 </div>
```

another way because you are using the reactive form you can track the gender value change like this

```
isMale :boolean;

ngOnInit() {

this.messageForm.get('gender').valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
 this.isMale = newValue === 'male'
});

}
```

*template*

```
<div *ngIf="isMale"> ... </div>
```